# loop logic for storing multi record in laravel?

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $productId = $request->id;
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'quantity' => 'required|integer|gt:0',
        'fmcode',
        'fmcodes',
        'area',
        'naoffm','glno'
        ]);
      
    for ($i = 0; $i<=$request->GLNO; $i++){
          
        $product = Product::updateOrCreate(
                [
                    'id' => $productId
                ],
               
                [
                    'id'=>$productId,
                    'name' => $request->name,
                    'quantity' => $request->quantity,
                    'fmcode' => $request->FMCODE,
                    'fmcodes' => $request->FMCODES,
                    'area' => $request->AREA,
                    'naoffm' => $request->NAOFFM,
                    'id'=>$request->GLNO[$i],
                    'glno'=>$request->GLNO[$i],
                ]
            );
        }
        
        return Response()->json($product);
    }
```

selected dropdown of glno values have to store  multiple records with glno dropdownlist
and required loop logic to store request data so required solutions for this

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? Why is this tagged with MySQL and AJAX, but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple insertions using Query Builder. Sample;

```
DB:table('table_name')->insert(
 [
   'id' => 1,
   'name' => 'mkeremcansev' 
 ],
 [
   'id' => 2,
   'name' => 'John Doe'
 ]
);
```